# html not responding to outside js file changes

Tags: javascript, html

```html
//index.php
<head>
    
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>

<style></style>
</head>

<body>
<script>
callalert();
</script>

</body>





//test.js
function callalert() {
alert('Allertt');
}

eg: i change the fn completely to: callalert(msg) {
var msg;
alert(msg);
}

//and html to:

callalert('Hello!');

//and it wont change, it still says "Allertt"

Anything would be appreciated!
```

So recently i've tried to implement some `javascript` libraries to a webpage. But `html` wont call anything from other js files. I tried many things, calling simple functions from js files, and somtimes it works but when I delete the test, function the page will display the same result as the functions is still there. It will take a long time for it to respond to the changes of the js.
I even tried from diffrent devices.

Anything would be appreciated!

Edit: When i posted this i modified the function from 'Allertt' to 'Hello!'.
Now, that I checked after 5hrs the script is updated. Also, yes this is running online on a server.

Comment: please show what you have tried, post your code.

Comment: Are you running that code on a server? In that case it could be possible that `test.js` got cached by the server.

Comment: @Stephan I dont think so. I tried from diffrent IPs or ISPs and the result is the same

Comment: Which web browser? I had the same problem, especially in Chrome, because the browser wasn't re-loading the JavaScript.

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Internet Explorer, the steps suggested here show how to force IE and Chrome to re-load JavaScript files every time, which might help you: https://superuser.com/questions/1195404/force-google-chrome-to-check-for-new-javascript-files-every-time-i-access-a-web

Answer (score -1):

I have prepared an example for you, which works perfectly:

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>
    myFun();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**External JS**

```
function myFun(){
    alert('test');
}
```

This calls myFun from external file, on every refresh, like it should.

Comment: The OP has nearly an identical setup and still he says that it doesn't change after editing.